# Sharepoint Infopath plus one extra database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I have the following setup:

Sharepoint 2010 with SQL Server and Office 2010.

This is the situation I have. Non programmers are supposed to create simple infopath forms. Admins then upload those to sharepoint, which will get served to users as simple webpages.

When a user submits the form it's fields are supposed to be stored in a separate SQL database, and after saving an email gets sent out to some address.

Whatever I try ends up with a situation that will not work.

Here are some of the problems I have had.
- Creating the Infopath form, from a database, prevents the fields to be stored in the database, because that is not supported from a webpage.
- Creating a normal form and uploading it to sharepoint, prevents me from getting access to the fields in the form, so that I could store them in a separate database. This is so because new completed forms get saved as documents in sharepoint, not as database rows.
- Using code in an infopath form, means that the form needs to deployed as sandboxed project, which prevents using it as webpage.

Any help on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: create a webservice on top of your database. You infopath form can send it's data to the webservice, the webservice can store the data in SQL server.

Option 2: save the forms to a forms library. Attach an eventhandler to that forms library that deserializes the XML and put the data in SQL server.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into option 2. Just need to figure out how to attach an eventhandler.